# Количество значений больше чем предыдущие за N период

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как создать новую колонку в датафрейме с количеством значений больших чем предыдущие за определенный период?

Пример. N=4

```
Вход    Выход

5       0  
6       0  
7       0  
5       2  
6       2  
4       1  
3       1  
4       1  
5       1  
7       3  
8       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
    col  res
0     5    0
1     6    0
2     7    0
3     5    2
4     6    2
5     4    1
6     3    1
7     4    1
8     5    1
9     7    3
10    8    3
```

Решение - используем [pandas.Series.rolling(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
In [34]: N = 4

In [35]: df["new"] = (df["col"]
                      .rolling(N)
                      .apply(lambda x: x.diff().gt(0).sum(), raw=False)
                      .fillna(0))
```

Результат:

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]:
    col  res  new
0     5    0  0.0
1     6    0  0.0
2     7    0  0.0
3     5    2  2.0
4     6    2  2.0
5     4    1  1.0
6     3    1  1.0
7     4    1  1.0
8     5    1  2.0
9     7    3  3.0
10    8    3  3.0
```

Проверка:

```
In [37]: df["res"] == df["new"]
Out[37]:
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8     False   # <--- по-моему, вы ошиблись в расчетах для этой строки
9      True
10     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Да, Вы правы. В 8 строке была ошибка.

А как модифицировать сей код, чтобы проверялось не предыдущее значение, а значение M шагов назад?

Comment: @jshapen, что значит "M шагов назад"? По-моему стоит задать новый вопрос с небольшим примером данных (как в данном вопросе), чтобы было понятно что вы хотите получить...

Comment: В текущем вопросе сравнивается текущее значение с предыдущим, т.е. на 1 шаг назад от текущего. А как сделать на М шагов от текущего?

Comment: @jshapen, `x.diff(M)...`

Comment: А, т.е. diff без параметров это на один шаг. Понял.
Спасибо еще раз.